# Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: google is not defined in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic3

I'm trying to include google map in my app. But i'm not getting google is not defined error.
I have added the  plugin

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation
```

My code is like:

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.loadMap();
  }
  loadMap(){

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  }
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: how did you include google maps? the javascript library or ionic native plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you installed (cordova-plugin-geolocation) just provides you with the user location. It does not include Google Maps API with it.

To use Google maps you can either:

- Use Google Maps cordova plugin:
  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/
- Use Google Maps JS API, example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple